# Xcode says: "use of undeclared type" and "'{' after 'if' condition". Other threads on this site don't have the answer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Have tried nearly anything to find out why this is telling me it isn't working. Maybe someone could help me with this. Note: I have tried calling the FeatureView -> featureView and it doesn't work.

[image: the line with the 2 so-called errors, the "if" at the beginning and the "FeatureView" at the end]

Comment: Don't post image of code. Paste your code here.

Comment: And just add `{` after `as? FeatureView` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please, post code, not screenshot.
2. You forgot { set the end of this line.

I mean you have to use 
`if let featureView = ... {`

3. FeatureView class doesn't exist in your project. So, xcode don't know that does this word mean.